# Cant import and show a vector in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

This is what I have done.

```
from qgis.core import *
layer = iface.addVectorLayer(r"C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\coastline.shp","coast","ogr")
```

or

```
from qgis.core import *
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\coastline.shp","coast","ogr")
```

Basically it doesn't even appear in the Layers section of QGIS.

The first one says layer is not valid
and the second it doesn't cause any problems but it isn't in the layers at all of Qgis?

Comment: How about r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\coastline.shp" as the path? The r implies that you don't need to escape backslashes, and you were missing a "\" after "C:".

Comment: It had the same effect. Why it doesn't show up in the Layers section?

Comment: What is the difference between the two approaches you show? Does the file show content when loading via drag-and-drop? Does a "Select CRS" window appear, maybe in the background?

Comment: i got what you meant check now these two approaches to see the differences.

Comment: Loading a layer is one thing, another is to register it with the canvas/legend. I strongly recommend the pyqgis cookbook: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#id3

Comment: @user122244 Try loading it manually by drag and drop if you get the same error as the first method you used `iface.addVectorLayer` then something is wrong with your shapefile, possibly a missing file

Answer (score 3):

```
from qgis.core import *
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\coastline.shp","coast","ogr")
```

just loads the specified layer to a variable named "layer" to load layer into QGIS mapcanvas do something like this for QGIS 3.x

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

or

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

for QGIS 2.x